# WPF/C# Add new style pop up form

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, popup

Quick question: I have a very busy form going on that I have developed for information about say book records.

I want to design an 'add new book form' that is essentially a pop up to input the info. What is the best way to do this? Use a Usercontrol that is called on a button click or menu click? an entire new form?

Have seen this type of functionality, but never designed it in a pop up have just had user input info on the actual form - and it can get very busy.

Thanks for any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd follow a common UI idiom. Which is, from a menu choose "new". This would popup a modal dialog to accept information about the new book form. I'd use the "Popup" control for this dialog. Within this Popup control, I'd embed the actual input dialog which is implemented as a user control.

The [popup control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) is part of the .Net framework. If you can't see the control in the VS2008 designer, then you can still use it by typing the Popup element directly in the text view of the .xaml file.

Comment: I was hoping to use the "Stock" controls of VS 2008, this control looks like an extension/addon ? not in my toolbox controls anyway...